# Simulate an ECONNRESET error on a Node.js net.Socket instance

Tags: node.js, unit-testing

I'm writing some unit tests and I'd like to simulate a connection loss (ECONNRESET) on a net.Socket instance as part of one of the tests.

What would be the best way to go about doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way I went for in the end was as follows:

```
client.end();
client.emit('error', new Error('ECONNRESET'));
```

was all I needed for the purposes of the test

Answer (score 2):

There is a bit more short-hand solution existing for such cases:

```
socket.destroy(new Error('ECONNRESET'))
```

According to `socket.destroy([exception])` [docs](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/net.html#net_socket_destroy_exception):

> If exception is specified, an 'error' event will be emitted and any
>   listeners for that event will receive exception as an argument.

Also, there is a subtle difference between `end` (it is possible the server will still send some data) and `destroy` (ensures that no more I/O activity happens on this socket). For `ECONNRESET` the latter would be the best choice as this code generally means abrupt peer disconnection and will error on subsequent writes.