# how to simulate ECONNRESET in npm mysql2 nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am using [npm mysql2 package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2) for connection to mysql in nodeJS application.

#### Introduction to the error

As it was discussed numerous times, an error of ECONNRESET may occur randomly, sometimes even on a production server only. The cause for this, traditionally, if the closed connection by the mysql server end after idle time. These discussions can be seen for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52978278/node-js-mysqland-mysql2-econnreset), the answer is traditionally to increase the idle timeout. The example of the error output can be seen here:

```
Sep 16 07:29:54 PM  Error: read ECONNRESET
Sep 16 07:29:54 PM      at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:209:20) {
Sep 16 07:29:54 PM    errno: -104,
Sep 16 07:29:54 PM    code: 'ECONNRESET',
Sep 16 07:29:54 PM    syscall: 'read',
Sep 16 07:29:54 PM    fatal: true
Sep 16 07:29:54 PM  }
```

However, since this error occurs after like 15 minutes (when the application is deployed on [render.com](https://dashboard.render.com/), and the application performs an sql insert query after some time), it is difficult to develop and debug this (or implement error controls).
Also, as some answers suggest to ping the sql periodically to keep it alive, I do not like this solution. I want to implement auto reconnecting mysql feature, when the sql connection is needed by the application (as it is cleaner solution than keeping a connection alive when it is not used)

#### The question

How can I generate the ECONNRESET on a localhost mysql running on my computer? My localhost mysql is MariaDB version of 8.0.29, and windows OS.

- I tried to kill the mysql service, while the nodeJS application was running, but that generated **connection refused error** instead
- a similar question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22836424/simulate-an-econnreset-error-on-a-node-js-net-socket-instance), but it adresses net.Socket instances, not the [npm mysql2 package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2). As I red the documentation of the [npm mysql2 package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2), I did not find similar functions for destroying the connection with an error raise that would suit my needs
- I tried to set the mysql wait_timeout value to low value, including the session one, or global one, but it still did not raise the ECONNRESET error on the localhost within short time

Comment: " I want to implement auto reconnecting mysql feature, when the sql connection is needed by the application (as it is cleaner solution than keeping a connection alive when it is not used)": in other words a connection pool. This is the correct solution, and implementations already exist. Your quest for a way to simulate ECONNRESET is an XY problem.

Comment: I am using connection pool, but still the error happens, there were various threads about his, other people facing the same issue (https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2/issues/128), I quote ,,could be anything - server idle timeout, network issues etc". It seems that eighter there is a bug in the library, where the connection is re-used, even though is no longer valid due to ECONNRESET, or just a network error may occur, as in network many things can go wrong and no code is really 100% bulletproof. Therefore, I see no other way to make it work other than implementing custom try-catch.